# command to write symbol as text (Resharper? VS2010?)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, resharper

I was watching a screencast of someone using Resharper (on VS 2010 or 2008, not sure) where they were able to fill in a test name with a string literal:

```csh
public class FooTest
{
    public void "runs backgrounnd process until complete"
```

and then some command transformed it to

```csh
public class FooTest
{
    public void runs_backgrounnd_process_until_complete()
    {
```

I was wondering if anyone knew what that command was.

Comment: May we, also, know the URL of this screencast?

Comment: I didn't think I'd be able to find it.  But I did http://www.iamnotmyself.com/2009/10/23/TDDKataCalculatorDemonstration.aspx.  Maybe it has audio?  Not on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a visual studio macro that originally came from JP Boodhoo's Nothing But .NET Boot Camp class. This is it:

```
 Sub ConvertLine()
        If DTE.ActiveDocument Is Nothing Then Return

        Dim isOpen As Boolean = OpenUndo("ConvertLine")

        Dim selection As TextSelection = CType(DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection(), EnvDTE.TextSelection)
        selection.SelectLine()
        If selection.Text = "" Then Return

        Dim classKeyword As String = "class """
        Dim methodKeyword As String = "void """
        Dim classIndex As Integer = selection.Text.IndexOf(classKeyword)
        Dim methodIndex As Integer = selection.Text.IndexOf(methodKeyword)
        If classIndex + methodIndex < 0 Then Return

        Dim index = CType(IIf(classIndex >= 0, classIndex, methodIndex), Integer)
        Dim prefix = selection.Text.Substring(0, index) + CType(IIf(classIndex >= 0, classKeyword, methodKeyword), String)
        Dim description As String = selection.Text.Replace(prefix, String.Empty)

        Dim conversion As String = Common.ReplaceSpacesWithUnderscores(description)
        conversion = Common.ReplaceApostrophesWithUnderscores(conversion)
        conversion = Common.ReplaceQuotesWithUnderscores(conversion)

        selection.Text = prefix.Replace("""", String.Empty) + conversion
        If prefix.Contains(methodKeyword) Then selection.LineDown() Else selection.LineUp()
        selection.EndOfLine()

        CloseUndo(isOpen)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Ahh and here is JP's original post on it.  http://blog.jpboodhoo.com/MacroToAidBDDTestNamingStyle.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a "live template".  If you notice, he types in `fact`, which is then replaced by the test method's skeleton.  Edit, looks like it comes from the [xUnit.net contrib](http://xunitcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ReSharperLiveTemplates&ProjectName=xunitcontrib) project.  You should be able to do something similar for an nUnit test case as well.